# Blazor: call secured API in OnTokenValidated

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I've to call a protected API during authorization. The API returns additional information for the user such as roles, groups, permissions ...

Both, the api and the blazor application, are registered in Azure AD B2C. Calling the API works after the authorization process is completed.

If I try to call the api during the event `OnTokenValidated` I'll get an error when trying to get a token.

> ErrorCode: user_null
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

I've tried to implement the token acquisition like here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/customization#how-to-query-microsoft-graph-on-token-validated

In Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);

        var prevOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            await prevOnTokenValidatedHandler(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await AuthorizationHelper.ValidateAADAppToken(context);
        };
    }
    
    )
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

In AuthorizationHelper

```
internal static async Task ValidateAADAppToken(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.TokenValidatedContext context)
        {
           
            ITokenAcquisition ta = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();

            var scopes = new[] { "https://<Tenant>/<ApiId>/access_as_user" };
            //var accessToken = await ta.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
            var accessToken = Task.Run(() => ta.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7297/WeatherForecast");


        }
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74827877/cannot-get-a-blazor-server-app-to-call-a-secure-downstream-web-api-using-azure-a/74928813#74928813

Answer (score 0):

If app has other  scopes in the portal make sure to include them in the scopes before running to call downstream api for and check if admin has consented and make sure it is consented.

[image]

MsalUiRequiredException occurs if correct scopes and permissions are not assigned. so make sure that you have granted sufficient permissions to your application and granted admin consent to that permission.

Make use of [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]  to filter the error.

Referred the code from: [c# - MsalUiRequiredException when calling Microsoft Graph SDK from NET Core web app - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490775/msaluirequiredexception-when-calling-microsoft-graph-sdk-from-net-core-web-app) by *qJake*

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
                if (httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
                {
                    var tokenService = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
                    try
                    {
                        token = await tokenService.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { scopes });
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                       ex.message();
                    }
                }
```

And use ExceptionHandler

[image]

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
{
    ExceptionHandler = async ctx => {
        var feature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (feature?.Error is MsalUiRequiredException
            or { InnerException: MsalUiRequiredException }
           )
        {
            ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete($"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix}{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}");
            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery());
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Reference: [Blazor server authorized downstream API call with Azure AD B2C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585961/blazor-server-authorized-downstream-api-call-with-azure-ad-b2c#:%7E:text=As%20an%20alternative%2C%20you%20can%20request%20access%20tokens,to%20use%20a%20standard%20HttpClient%20instead%20of%20IDownstreamWebApi.)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy.
"GetAccessTokenForUserAsync" defaults to HttpContext.Current.User for the user parameter.

In your case, HttpContext.Current.User is not set yet since you're inside the OnTokenValidated event.

You can pass the ClaimsPrinciple from the OnTokenValidatedContext (or eventArgs) to GetAccessTokenForUserAsync